# Can I get a email data from Database in Notification Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, email-notifications

EDIT: What i want is having a new subscribers email to show at email notification. i want to get those email that has been stored in database to be displayed in the email form below.

after the sentence You have a new subscriber:
it will show the new email of the new subscribers

[image]

this is my Notify

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $subscribers = Subscribe::where('email', '!=', null)->first();

    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject('You have a new subscriber')
                ->line('You have a new subscriber:', $subscribers)
                ->action('Click Here', url('/subscribe'));
                // ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

how can i make this work?

*sorry for my bad english

Comment: Explain better your problem. What you want to do and what its the actual behaviour

Comment: So there is a new subscriber, and they had an email. i want to get those email that has been stored in database to be displayed @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro

Comment: `$user->notify(new AwesomeNotification($dataToShow));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just some little problems in your script:

Change *comma* to a *dot* here:

```
->line('You have a new subscriber:', $subscribers)
```

Fetch email property of your object. Like so:

```
$subscribers->email;
```

And if you wanna get newest subscriber (and you table contains laravel timestamps)

```
Subscribe::where('email', '!=', null)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first();
```

To sum up, then, you code should look like that:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $subscribers = Subscribe::where('email', '!=', null)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first();

    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject('You have a new subscriber')
                ->line('You have a new subscriber:'.$subscribers->email)
                ->action('Click Here', url('/subscribe'));
                // ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```